# Can I invert the way a ttk.Notebook show the content frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

Hi I am trying to make a program with tabs. And i was wondering if a could use ttk.Notebook inverted. Like in Excel, the tabs are on the bottom but the content frame shows on top. So I was wondering if anyone know if it is possible and wish that if it does...Can someone explain me how? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909169/python-tkinter-side-notebook-tabs/46909876#46909876